next.js caches routes returning 404
I have a dynamic route. Using generateStaticParams creates static paths for me at build time. So far everything is normal.
However, navigating to a new route in runtime causes that route to be created statically. even if the page returns 404.
This is not a desired situation. Because non-existent routes take up unnecessary cache space.
export dynamicParams = false

When I set the parameter to false, it returns 404 for all routes except the routes during build.
export dynamicParams = true

When I set the parameter to true, it caches every route taken, even if the route returns a 404.
How should I add a new route when the user creates a new page from cms? my code is as below
/app/[[...slug]]/page.js
export const dynamicParams = true;

export default async function generateStaticContent({ params }) {

    const { isEnabled } = draftMode();

    const config = await getRouteConfig(params, isEnabled);

    if(config.error) return notFound();

    return produceContent(config);
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    return produceRoutes();
}

